# Transistor circuit design review

Tags: transistors, switches, gpio

I have a customer requirement where we have to design a GPIO controlled switch. We are using NPN transistor, where when the GPIO is high(3.3V) transistor is enabled and it acts as closed switch, when GPIO is driven low(0V) transistor is disabled and acts as closed switch.
When the transistor is enabled the voltage across emitter is used to enable the regulator.

The below is the attached circuit image. When the transistor is enabled what will be the voltage across emitter pin.[image: Transistor circuit image]

Comment: You're feeding this buffer with 12 V. Why? What are the threshold levels of the device you're driving? ([Edit] the question rather than bury details in the comments.)

Comment: Is this supposed to drive a load at R1_EN?

Comment: Yes. Its used to drive load at R1_EN  and it has a threshold of 1.8V.

Comment: R157 is entirely redundant btw, Once C44 is charged up to ~2.7V (GPIO_POWER_EN=3.3V)  how does it discharge to the 'off' condition again ?

Comment: Again, [edit] the question rather than bury details in the comments.

Comment: the voltage across the pin will be 0V because the voltage at one end of the pin will be the same as the voltage at the other end of the pin. But I don't think that you asked the right question.

Answer (score 1):

When GPIO_POWER_EN is high, then R1_EN will be at the voltage of GPIO_POWER_EN - 0.7 V, the transistor is acting as an emitter follower.

If you need a high side switch then something like the following would work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faJRafm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The collector is connected to a voltage of 12V. Wont that make any difference to voltage across collector when its ON.

Comment: No, you have an emitter follower, when the base emitter junction is forward biased, the emitter will be ~0.7 V below the base, the transistor will turn the (12 V - emitter voltage) * emitter current into heat.

Answer (score 1):

You've designed an emitter-follower circuit. The voltage at Q14's emitter will be at least 0.7 V lower than the GPIO and on a 3.3 V supply that's nearly 25% of a voltage loss. This might be OK but we don't know what you're trying to drive with this circuit.

You need to specify the requirements of the device you're driving.

- What is the maximum voltage allowed for a logic 0?
- What is the minimum voltage required for a logic 1?

Note that your circuit can only turn the enable line on. Once the capacitor charges up there is no way to discharge it unless there is a pull-down resistor that you haven't shown us. It will stay on.

Comment: What is the maximum voltage allowed for a logic 0 -0.6V  
What is the minimum voltage required for a logic 1 -1.6V

Comment: You tell us. You haven't told us what you're driving. If the 1.8 V you've mentioned in the comments (instead of adding into your question as recommended) then the logic 0 maximum voltage will be, perhaps, 1 to 1.2 V but you have to look this up.

Comment: We are using it to enable a regulator whole VIH(min)=1.6V

Comment: @Shifali Can you clarify your question, what it is exactly you're trying to do? If it's to enable something, with a threshold of 1.6 V, can you not drive it straight from the GPIO?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with this circuit. The first problem may not be a problem if your only driving a low current logic signal. If you draw too much current (more than 0.8 mA) then the voltage drop across R159 will bring the voltage at R1_EN under your threshold of 1.8V. Since you didn't specify the load, you have to decide if this is a problem.

If you do have a low-current, logic signal, then the other problem is that when the transistor is turned off, there no way for the capacitor to discharge. This will leave the voltage at R1_EN high until the leakage currents discharge the capacitor which can take a long time. To remedy this problem, add a resistor in parallel to the capacitor to discharge it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the load presented to the circuit at RL_EN the circuit is somewhat impossible to model meaningfully.

Also, you don't measure a voltage 'across a pin'. Please state accurately what you mean.

R157 is entirely redundant. R158 may also be redundant. R159 and C44 may also be redundant.

You ask ..  'When the transistor is enabled what will be the voltage across emitter pin.' That depends what you mean by 'enabled' and what you mean by 'across emitter pin' !

I can only respond by attempting to best interpret your question that if you apply 3.3V to GPIO_POWER_EN then the voltage at Q14 will be ~2.7V. It will stay at 2.7V almost indefinitely in the circuit as drawn.

Would you like a better circuit ?